# How to share Desktop PC internet with android

Tags: internet, android

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on my desktop pc . I've a android phone with kitkat update . I'm using a broadband line for internet . Now how can I use my pc internet in my android phone . I can do in on Windows 8 . But what about ubuntu ?

Comment: related on android.SE [How to set up reverse tethering over usb?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/6480)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go to the dash and search for "Network" and open the application:

[image: Dash Search Network]

Once open it should show a window similar to this:

[image: Network Panel]

From here click on the "Use a Hotspot..." button. Doing this will disconnect your wireless adapter from its current access point (if it has one) and start an Ad-Hoc Wireless Hotspot. The panel in the network panel should now have changed to this:

[image: Network Panel - Wireless Hotspot]

Now all you have to do is scan for the hotspot on your phone and enter the proper security information to connect to the network.